# Yii 2 – Can't use Model Update

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have some code:

```
public function actionEditpost($id) {
    $post = SiteBlogPosts::find()->
            where(["id" => $id])->
            asArray()->
            one();

    $model = new SiteBlogPosts();
    $model->id = $post['id'];
    $model->DateCreated = $post['DateCreated'];
    $model->Author = $post['Author'];
    $model->Title = $post['Title'];
    $model->PreviewText = $post['PreviewText'];
    $model->FullTextOfPost = $post['FullTextOfPost'];
    $model->CategoryID = $post['CategoryID'];

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        if ($model->validate()) {

            $model->update();
            print_r($model);
            die;
            return $this->render('AddPostDone', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    } else {
        $cats = SiteBlogCats::find()->where(["CatIsActive" => 1])->asArray()->all();
        return $this->render('EditPost', ['cats' => $cats,
                    "model" => $model,
                    'oldPost' => $post,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This code works incorrectly - it doesn't update record in MySQL.
In `/runtime/debug` logs I found interesting moment:

> ```
> "UPDATE `SiteBlogPosts` SET `id`=5, `DateCreated`='2015-06-11', `Author`=1,
>   `Title`='We are improved build mode!',
>   `PreviewText`='<div class=\"post-content\">\r\n<p>Hi.</p>\r\n\r\n<p></p>\r\n\r\n<p>We are improved build mode! Also, we added simple Mirror Material Test.</p>\r\n\r\n<p><iframe height=\"350\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/FLQ4i_av7HM\" width=\"425\"></iframe></p>\r\n</div>\r\n',
>   `FullTextOfPost`='<div class=\"post-content\">\r\n<p>Hi.</p>\r\n\r\n<p></p>\r\n\r\n<p>We are improved build mode! Also, we added simple Mirror Material Test.</p>\r\n\r\n<p><iframe height=\"350\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/FLQ4i_av7HM\" width=\"425\"></iframe></p>\r\n</div>\r\n',
>   `CategoryID`=1 
> WHERE `id` IS NULL"
> ```

Otherwise, `print_r` shows:

```
app\models\SiteBlogPosts Object
(
    [sqlCreateQuery] => 
    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [DateCreated] => 2015-06-11
            [Author] => 1
            [Title] => We are improved build mode!
            [PreviewText] => <div class="post-content">
<p>Hi.</p>

<p></p>

<p>We are improved build mode! Also, we added simple Mirror Material Test.</p>

<p><iframe height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FLQ4i_av7HM" width="425"></iframe></p>
</div>
```

Why it used `WHERE id IS NULL` instead of `WHERE id = 5`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
   public function actionEditpost($id) {
        $model = SiteBlogPosts::find()->
                where(["id" => $id])->
                one();

        $cats = SiteBlogCats::find()->where(["CatIsActive" => 1])->asArray()->all();


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            if ($model->validate()) {
                $model->update();
//                print_r($model);
//                die;
                return $this->render('EditPost', ['cats' => $cats,
                            "model" => $model,
                ]);
            }
        } else {
            return $this->render('EditPost', ['cats' => $cats,
                        "model" => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the full content of your model `SiteBlogPosts` ? Try add the id as a required field  on `rules()`: `[['id'], 'required'],`

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 ActiveRecord default use table **id** as primary key .

you can not set id :

```
  $model->id = $post['id'];
```

if you have an other primary key you can use the following code in your **SiteBlogPosts** model and change yii2 default primary column.

```
public static function primaryKey()
{
    return "your_column";
}
```